# Printing non ascii characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a JSON with non ascii value:

```
my_json =  { 'mykey': 'bbür'}
```

I am trying to print or display this JSON and what I see is:

```
print my_json 
{'mykey': 'bb\xc3\xbcr'}
```

I want to print or display like:

```
{ 'mykey': 'bbür'}
```

I googled and tried the following but it seems not to be working:

```
print unicode(my_json).encode('utf-8')
print unicode(my_json).decode('utf-8')
print unicode(my_json).encode('ascii')
print unicode(my_json).encode('ascii')
print ord(j['mykey'])
```

Comment: that is not possible in python2 to my knowledge.

Comment: Exactly. In python 3 you won't have such problem

Comment: That's not "a JSON", it's a Python dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

First, `my_json` is not json but a Python `dict`.
Printing a Python `dict` means printing the result of the `dict.__str__()` method.

If you really want to print this dict the way you want, you can potentially make a sub-class of `dict` and override the `__str__` method:

```
# coding: utf8

class MyDict(dict):
    def __str__(self):
        kv_pairs = ('"%s": "%s"' % (key, val) for key, val in self.iteritems())
        return '{%s}' % ', '.join(kv_pairs)


my_json =  {'mykey': 'bbür'}

print MyDict(my_json)  # {"mykey": "bbür"}
```

However, I would not advice to do something like this. You should rather make a function to display you dict the way you want.